# How can I choose my squadmates in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Mass Effect 3 I have trouble choosing my squadmates, as the choice seems to be made for me. Twice now Shepherd has told a squadmate to go and do something which means they leave my squad.

When encountering Liara, James gets ordered away and when encountering Garrus, Liara gets sent away.

Is there a way to choose who gets sent away?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, these are decisions made for you early in the game, in part so you can use your new squadmates. The game doesn't let you decide much on the first two missions.

After the intro missions you'll always choose your squadmates each time you go on a mission, the choice is completely yours.

Answer (score 1):

No,but at times you can choose someone to do a specific action (like when you are on the moon you have to choose who to asign to fix the com tower)